# Which switches are necessary to be specified when invoking latex?

Tags: compiling

By default TeXnicCenter activates `--src -interaction=nonstopmode`. The following screenshot shows the other switches but `--src` does not exist there.

[image]

Shortly speaking,

1. What is `--src` for?
2. Which is the correct one, `-src` or `--src`?
3. Which switches are necessary to be specified when invoking `latex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's short for `--src-specials`; options can be shortened as long as they are unambiguous.
2. Both are legal.
3. Those that you feel necessary.

I would not use `--src-specials`, for it is an old method for synchronization between source and output, which is superseded by `--synctex=1` (although I don't really know whether DVI previewers support the latter).

Comment: +1 Do I need to use `--src` if I have PSTricks code in my document? Because internally PSTricks uses special, right?

Comment: No, they have nothing to do with each other.